# Screenspace UIs present in front of camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way in Unity to implement the UIs present in screenspace canvas to be present also in front of the camera in VR? That is screenspace UIs -> Worldspace Camera. The UIs can be adjusted with the scale and be kept right infront of the camera? Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik in VR a `ScreenSpace - Overlay` isn't rendered **at all**. This makes sense because anyway the canvas would have `0` distance to the Camera/Eyes which would cause an extremely unpleasant experience.

I can not say much about `ScreenSpace - Camera` but at least per [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html) it sets the canvas always at a certain distance to the Camera and is automatically scaled to fill the entire view rect.

---

However, actually the best user experience is usually using a `Worldspace` canvas and always position it about 1.5 meters in front of your head.

Additionally you could lerp it a bit e.g. like

```
public class KeepInFrontOfHead : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Camera _mainCamera;
    [SerializeField] private float _offset = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField][Range(0f,1f)] private float _interpolationRate = 0.5f;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_mainCamera) _mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        var targetPosition = _mainCamera.transform.position + _mainCamera.transform.forward * _offset;

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, _interpolationRate); 

        var targetRotation = Camera.transform.eulerAngles;
        targetRotation.z = 0;
        transform.eulerAngles = targetRotation;
    }
}
```